# How to delete the beginning of nginx uri

Tags: nginx, uri, proxypass

i want to change my recived uri inside the Nginx location.

this is the url recived to my Nginx | >>> **mywebsite.com/google.com/about**

and its what i want | >>> cut **google.com** from `uri` and just only send **/about** to my `proxy_pass`

**/about** in uri is something dynamic and it can be anything

this is my config

```
    location /google.com {
            rewrite   # This is where I do not know what to do
           proxy_pass http://google.com;
           proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you append an "optional URI" to the `proxy_pass` value, the request will be modified before passing upstream. See [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

You want to substitute `/google.com/` with `/`, so you should append a trailing `/` to both the `location` and `proxy_pass` values.

For example:

```
location /example.com/ {
    proxy_pass http://example.com/;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To complete the Richard's answer, there are two techniques to change an URI that to be passed to the upstream.

1. With a prefix location, you can strip the prefix specifying another URI with a `proxy_pass` directive, like already shown:

   ```
   location <old_prefix> {
       proxy_pass <scheme>://<upstream><new_prefix>;
   }
   ```

   This way an old prefix will be stripped from the beginning of the request URI, and a new prefix will be added instead.
2. You can use a `rewrite` rule to modify a request URI whatever way you want to. To strip some prefix like `/google.com` you can use

   ```
   location /google.com {
       rewrite ^/google\.com(.*) $1;
       proxy_pass <scheme>://<upstream>;
   }
   ```

   Note that no additional URI part should be specified after the upstream name for the `proxy_pass` directive in this case.

The first one can be used only with prefix location. However it is more performant than the second one and should be preferred whenever possible. On the other hand the second is the only one that can be used in the regex matching or named locations.

There is an important caveat with the second example. Any proper request URI should start with a slash. However used prefix location will match anything started with `/google.com`, e.g. `/google.company` and the rewritten URI will be an invalid `pany` one (an invalid because it does not start with a slash). So using `location /google.com/ { ... }` instead will be more safe.

You can use the following location to allow exact `/google.com` request URI to be processed too:

```
location = /google.com {
    rewrite ^ /google.com/ last;
}
```

or a single rewrite rule at the `server` block level:

```
rewrite ^/google\.com$ /google.com/;
```

Or you can use a regex matching location and slightly modified rewrite rule:

```
location ^ /google\.com(?:/|$) {
    # ensure the rewritten URI will start with a slash
    rewrite ^/google\.com/?(.*) /$1;
    proxy_pass <scheme>://<upstream>;
}
```